# Vote counts don't wrap properly in display of linked questions with votes >= 100

Tags: bug, status-completed

In the linked questions feed (for example, on [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/55523/17062)), the vote counts don't wrap properly for certain questions.

[image: linked questions bug]

I'm using Chromium 33.0.1750.152 on Debian testing, and I also see this behaviour on Iceweasel 24.4 on the same OS. Also, I'm using the default zoom settings for both browsers.

Comment: Using chrome on Debian Ubuntu 12,04 happens here too

Comment: Happens on Askubuntu too, so I reported it on [Meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229428/150311).

Comment: @Lekensteyn Do you think the meta.SO question would get more attention if the title matched this one?

Comment: I don't know, I have edited the question title anyway to mention `>= 100`

Comment: If I change the zoom to anything other than 100%, it's "fixed" (not really a fix though, just an observation that it's perhaps very on-the-edge)  Happens in Windows 7, Chrome 34.

Comment: I took a look and this appears to be fixed.